# El mejor sitio en stackexchange para recomendacion de software/herramientas/etc en el mundo de software

Tags: discusión, wiki-de-comunidad

se han topado ustedes con preguntas tipo:

> *Cual es el mejor libreria o herramientas para crear efectos en mi sitio web*

R: **JQuery**

aunque la mayoria de este tipo de preguntas son eliminadas rapidamente de stackoverflow en español, yo  siempre me he preguntado si los usuarios no miran el menu de **stackexchange** donde pueden encontrar el sitio **[Software Recommendatios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)**

si miramos su descripcion en ingles literalmente dice: **para personas que buscan software espeficos**

yo siempre cuando veo preguntas similares a la anterior siempre recomiendo visitar este sitio aunque yo podria entender que algunos usuarios no tienen un dominio intermedio en el ingles y  me podrian decir que no hacen preguntas ahi porque esta en ingles, mi pregunta  es se podria agregar las etiquetas de Software Recommendations en stackoverflow en español?

> Software Recommendations For people seeking specific software
>   recommendations

yo recomiendo este sitio siempre porque  su proposito es recomendar software para 
 determinadas tareas o problemas por ejemplo aqui esta una preguntas sobre un usuario que buscas si existe algun software para su problema:

[software-to-create-ebooks-with-markdown](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53572/software-to-create-ebooks-with-markdown)

aunque no es sobre programacion pero es sobre recomendacion de software y yo creo que este sitio seria el adecuado mencionar cuando se creen preguntas sobre recomendaciones de software y no solo eliminar la pregunta sin ninguna recomendacion  donde pregunta.

¿Que opinas? si gustas expresar tu opinion con gusto me gustaria leerla en los comentarios.

Comment: Creo que sería interesante y no se pierde nada por dejar un comentario de ese tipo, pero nos podemos encontrar con el problema del idioma: no todo el mundo sabe inglés y mucha gente viene aquí por eso.

Comment: yo por lo menos lo hago cuando se que algun sitio le va a dar una mejor respuesta. no esta mal. y si el usuario no sabe ingles es una pena.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pienso lo mismo :( bueno yo primero hice mi usuario en stackoverflow y despues me pase a stackoverflow en español :) y donde menciona esta parte "pero nos podemos encontrar con el problema del idioma" yo siempre he pensando en una idea para eso :) asi como se realiza en la traduccion del centro de ayuda deberia exisitir herramienta "magica"

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro  en stackoverflow con traduccion automatica del ingles  al español (no me refiero a google translate) una herramienta que analise cada palabra en un texto HTML5 y busque una traduccion mas exacta al español formal(mas comun entre los nativos)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro  con apoyo  voluntario , yo comento la anterior herramienta porque yo cuento conun proyecto personal donde realiza esa funcion actualmente mi proyecto solo funciona en local y traduce 100 palabras al español(MX) mas comun usado, aunque no considero que mi proyecto sea lo suficiente maduro para algo asi pero me gustaria compartirlo luego :) para ver sus opiniones, pero yo sugiero  algo asi :) nose que opines tu como moderador

Comment: @gbianchi pienso lo mismo :( yo entre primero al sitio de ingles y despues me pase aqui para ver que show por estos rumbos